# fullcalendar scheduler stopped working

Tags: fullcalendar-scheduler

I have fullcalendar scheduler script installed and everything was working fine for about 5 months. This week I noticed, that events are rendered only until Wednesday, August 10, 2016. After this day, no event is rendered, although data form db is loaded into the feed also behind this date.

http://www.slotenis.si/rezervacije/?lid=2

Strange problem, what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, my data source was limited to 500 records retrived from MySQL db. Once this limitation was removed, everything was working again.